# Is it possible to change the font size of TListView groups?

Tags: delphi, fonts, header, tlistview

Starting with Delphi 2009, the TListView component now offers the possibility to show items grouped using the Groups feature.

Is it possible to change the font size of just the groups header text? By default it uses the same font and size as the rest of the ListView items but I would like to increase the size of the groups header text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS, and thus the VCL, does not support customizing the font size of ListView group headers.

Comment: What about the font color?

Answer (score 0):

I found a really good piece of code here:

[To change a font for TListView header](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0158.htm)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know specifically, however in Delphi 2007 I play around with the Font Colour and Style of TListViews.

It would be worth looking at the

> AdvancedCustomDrawItem

method and look at doing something similar to the following:

> ListView.Canvas.Font.Size := 10;

Depending on the details of the specific Item being drawn in the routine

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately setting "  Sender.Canvas.Font.Size := 10;" on the AdvancedCustomDrawItem only applies to ListView items, not the Groups header text.